# Why can't I plot this dask dataframe with datashader (not enough values to unpack)?

Tags: python, dask, holoviews, datashader

I'd like to plot a large-ish graph with datashader + holoviews, but I am getting an error.
Something small and reproducible is:

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from holoviews.operation.datashader import (
    datashade, aggregate, dynspread,
    bundle_graph, split_dataframe,  regrid
)
from holoviews.element.graphs import layout_nodes
from datashader.layout import forceatlas2_layout, random_layout

hv.extension('bokeh')

targets = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
sources = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': sources, 'target': targets})
edges_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

graph = layout_nodes(hv.Graph(edges_df), layout=forceatlas2_layout)
forceatlas = bundle_graph(graph, split=False)
pad = dict(x=(-.5, 1.3), y=(-.5, 1.3))
datashade(forceatlas, width=800, height=800) * forceatlas.nodes.redim.range(**pad)
```

which fails with

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
>   ---> 17 graph = layout_nodes(hv.Graph(edges_df), layout=forceatlas2_layout)

However, setting `targets = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` I get a plot.
With the "faulty" `targets`, if I use `random_layout` instead of forceatlas2, I also get a plot.

I am puzzled! Why I am I getting that error and how to get rid of it? I am using datashader 0.7.0.

Comment: I now suspect this is a bug in the lib... I thus filed https://github.com/pyviz/datashader/issues/740

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the problematic line with
`graph = layout_nodes(hv.Graph(edges_df), layout=forceatlas2_layout, kwargs = {'id': 'index'})`

This should allow to cope with the library internals.